# Is there a way to ref a data type in typescript while declaring an angular2 data model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

In Mongoose, it has a way to refer to another data definition. I wonder if there is a way we can do while we are defining a data module for angular2?

In Mongoose

```
var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});
```

My question:

```
export class Person {
  _id     : number;
  name    : String;
  age     : Number;
  stories : [
      //sometype
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ha I found the answer for this.
Basically, what I need to do is declare another class like the following:

```
export interface Story {
    //some fields
}


import {Story} from "./story";

export class Person {
  _id     : number;
  name    : String;
  age     : Number;
  stories : [
      Story
  ]
}
```