# Finding object in nested tree array - TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a nested array something similar to folder structure.

```
<ul>
<li>
FolderA
<ul>
   <li>FolderA1</li>
   <li>FolderA2
        <ul>
           <li>FolderA21</li>
           <li>FolderA22</li>
           <li>FolderA23</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>FolderA3</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>FolderB
<ul>
   <li>FolderB1</li>
   <li>FolderB2</li>
   <li>FolderB3</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>FolderC</li>
</ul>

folder: {
label: string;
path: string;
children: folder[];}
```

Let's say if I need to insert new "FolderA221" , I will have to select it's parent "FolderA22" first and use push method. 
I tried using 'find' method but it actually works at level 1. is there any way to recursively find and select the object?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare another type and imported into your .ts file

```
import { Child } from './child';

export interface parent {
     field1: string;
     field2: Array<Child>;
}
```

This may solve your problem....

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43401029/4122814)